# Stanford CoreNLP wrapper crashing randomly running sentiments on a large number of texts

Tags: java, python-3.x, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have to run this wrapper to analyse the sentiment of about 120K comments.
It works for some and then crashes.
I thought it was timing or memory so i changed this command accordingly to this.
$ java -mx20g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -timeout 9999999
Then is still crashed so broke my file in to like 1400 files with like 85 comments each.
Any thought maybe run them in sequence in a loop reading the files.
Using Jupyter notebooks on a VM.
It broke again.
I tested it randomly and it works for some and does not work for some. It can read upto 3 files at a time too when it likes but only tends to break at some particular fixed comments, and pipeline gets killed.
Can you please guide me what might be the issue...
Here is what the error output looks like...
I hope someone can offer some guidance to me please.....Thanks!!

---

```
RemoteDisconnected                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    669             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 670             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    671                 conn,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    425                     # Otherwise it looks like a bug in the code.
--> 426                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    427         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    420                 try:
--> 421                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    422                 except BaseException as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
   1331             try:
-> 1332                 response.begin()
   1333             except ConnectionError:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/http/client.py in begin(self)
    302         while True:
--> 303             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    304             if status != CONTINUE:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
    271             # sending a valid response.
--> 272             raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    273                                      " response")

RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    438             if not chunked:
--> 439                 resp = conn.urlopen(
    440                     method=request.method,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    723 
--> 724             retries = retries.increment(
    725                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    402             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
--> 403                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    404             elif read is not None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    733             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 734                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    735             raise value

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    669             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 670             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    671                 conn,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    425                     # Otherwise it looks like a bug in the code.
--> 426                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    427         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    420                 try:
--> 421                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    422                 except BaseException as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
   1331             try:
-> 1332                 response.begin()
   1333             except ConnectionError:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/http/client.py in begin(self)
    302         while True:
--> 303             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    304             if status != CONTINUE:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
    271             # sending a valid response.
--> 272             raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    273                                      " response")

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-ee005c0cb92f> in <module>
     52 
     53         NLP_score_list = ""
---> 54         NLP_score_list= Sentiment_of_StanfordCoreNLP(str(cleaned_standalone_comment))
     55         print(NLP_score_list)
     56 

<ipython-input-12-4aaa83845d46> in Sentiment_of_StanfordCoreNLP(doc)
      3     Sent_list = []
      4 
----> 5     annot_doc = nlp_wrapper.annotate(doc,
      6     properties={
      7        'annotators': 'sentiment',

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycorenlp/corenlp.py in annotate(self, text, properties)
     24 
     25         data = text.encode()
---> 26         r = requests.post(
     27             self.server_url, params={
     28                 'properties': str(properties)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py in post(url, data, json, **kwargs)
    117     """
    118 
--> 119     return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
    120 
    121 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     59     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     60     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 61         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     62 
     63 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    528         }
    529         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 530         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    531 
    532         return resp

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    641 
    642         # Send the request
--> 643         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    496 
    497         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
--> 498             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    499 
    500         except MaxRetryError as e:

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Comment: Can you post an example request?

Comment: If you are trying to annotate comments with the server, you should probably submit one comment at a time.

Comment: That is, you should have each request correspond to a particular comment. You could of course run multiple threads at once.

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp -Thanks What do you mean ' run multiple threads at once' ? I simply have a file with many comments and i am running the request via python to read the file. I have many files i am running in a loop.I have opened the request to the pipeline before of course, but it crashes after a few analysis, with no fixed reason. I am trying to figure out the error output, what is it trying to tell me, why is it crashing out...is it memory, timer, or incomprehensible analysis...Thank you and please help me...

Comment: Please post the Python code you are using. You can run the Stanford CoreNLP server with multiple threads to increase throughput. Are the comments 1 per line in the file?

Comment: There is documentation here about using the Stanford CoreNLP server via Python: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/corenlp_client.html

Comment: My suggestion is to break your file up into comments, load the comments into memory and submit them 1 at a time to the server.

Comment: Thanks loads, I know it works swell for one at a time, but i have about 140,000 comments. I broke it into files with about 85 comments, it breaks for some and works smooth for upto 3 files even. The comments is breaks on work great on their own, just not part of a file being read, maybe because i observed tey are very long comments, what is the maximum time and memory I can have for the '$ java -mx20g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -timeout 9999999" command. Can u suggest it please? @StanfordNLPHelp

Comment: There is no speed advantage to sending a block of comments to the server as a large document, and that is quite possibly causing your issues. You should submit one comment at a time. You should be able to process more than one comment at a time by using more threads.

Comment: That being said, it should automatically use the max available threads on your machine.

Comment: The most likely problem you are facing is trying to parse very long sentences, so you can use the -parse.maxSentenceLength 100 (or whatever limit) to skip parsing long sentences.

Comment: But my main advice is that you should not be sending a 1600 comment document to the server as a single annotation request, it is not designed to handle that.

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp - Thanks so much! That explains so much!!! I blame myself less now. lol. Maybe i can skip the long ones and do them one by one later. Lets hope there arent too many of those. Also to be honest, i dont exactly know what exactly you  mean by 'use more threads', may you kindly please elaborate more on it with some example.. it is going through many comments one after the other in file, only breaking on the long ones in the file but not if that one is sent on its own alone.

Comment: ps i broke it to 85 comments a file, still only breaks on the longer comments, in the file, but not on its own.